# ServiceStack.Text serializing dictionaries

Tags: servicestack

I was using Json.Net to serialize dictionaries of type Dictionary, and when I added integers or booleans to the dictionary, when deserializing I would get integers and booleans back.
Now I was trying to change my code to use ServiceStack.Text instead because of a problem in other part of the code with the serialization of dates, but now I get the booleans an integers as strings after deserialization. Is there any way to have the same behaviour as Json.Net?

Here's the code to reproduce it: https://gist.github.com/1608951
Test_JsonNet passes, but both Test_ServiceStack_Text_TypeSerializer and Test_ServiceStack_Text_JsonSerializer fail

Comment: can you provide a code sample? i.e. what dictionary is causing the issues.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code that reproduces the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For untyped dynamic payloads it's better to use the [JSON Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils) in ServiceStack.Common which lets you parse dynamic payloads whilst preserving their type, e.g:

```cs
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
if (obj is new Dictionary<string, object> jsonObj) 
{
    int b = (int)jsonObj["b"];
    bool c = (bool)jsonObj["c"];
}
```

It's a purposeful design decision in [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) JSON Serializer that no type information is emitted for primitive value types which is why the values are left as strings.

You either have to deserialize into a strong typed POCO that holds the type info:

```
public class MixType
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public bool c{ get; set; }
}

var mixedMap = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "a", "text" },
    { "b", 32 },
    { "c", false },
};

var json = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(mixedMap);
Console.WriteLine("JSON:\n" + json);

var mixedType = json.FromJson<MixType>();
Assert.AreEqual("text", mixedType.a);
Assert.AreEqual(32, mixedType.b);
Assert.AreEqual(false, mixedType.c);
```

Or deserialize into a `Dictionary<string,string>` and parse into specific types yourself.

Or deserialize using ServiceStack's dynamic API. See [ServiceStack's Dynamic JSON Test folder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/tree/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/DynamicModels) for examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You can now do this:

```
JsConfig.TryToParsePrimitiveTypeValues = true;
```

Which will make the JSON deserialiser try to determine what the types should be, and you will get your integers back as integers, booleans back as booleans, etc.